# In ASP NET identity model [AspNetUsers].[ID] field is auto generated?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, identity

could you some one help me, whether in ASP NET identity model [AspNetUsers].[ID] field is auto generated or not?

While creating new user from C# code, value for the field [AspNetUsers].[ID]  need to be provided or it will auto generate the GUID for its own?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The GUID will be auto generated!

Answer (score 0):

You can leave the [AspNetUsers].[ID] as null and the ID will be automatically generated on creation.

Comment: Can I do insert from DB query directly,  Insert into [AspNetUsers] values(ID) ('some value'). Is that fine to do that or it is not good pratcice ?

Comment: @MagendranV Hi if you leave the ID field null it is fine to do.